# Length of file in file handling

Tags: python, file-handling

I try to find length of a text file in python in different ways. But I got doubt why they are showing such outputs.

**Text file:**

```
hello 
this is a sample text file.
say hi to python
```

**1st Try:**

```
size_to_read = 8

with open('sample.txt', "r") as f:
    f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)
    print(f'the total length of file is {len(f_contents)}')
    while len(f_contents) > 0:
        print(f_contents, end="**")
        f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)
```

**Output:**

[image: output1]

**2nd Try:**

```
size_to_read = 8

with open('sample.txt', "r") as f:
    f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)
    print(f'the total length of file is {len(f.read())}')
    while len(f_contents) > 0:
        print(f_contents, end="**")
        f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)
```

**Output:**

[image: output 2]

**3rd Try:**

```
size_to_read = 8

with open('sample.txt', "r") as f:
    f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)
    print(f'the total length of file is {len(f.readline())}')
    while len(f_contents) > 0:
        print(f_contents, end="**")
        f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Can anyone please explain why these 3 are giving different outputs.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind each of these tries?

Comment: The length as in number of chars? like the length of a string?

Comment: @ScottHunter I was just practicing file handling

Comment: If you read 8, you get no more than 8.  if you read -1, you get the whole file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to the read buffer.

**In First case:**
Initially you read the 8 bytes and then subsequently 8 bytes per while loop iteration. Thats why it is printing 8 bytes per print.

```
f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)  # read 8 bytes
```

NOTE: you haven't use `read` function while printing the len.

**In second case**
Initially you read 8 bytes but while printing the length you use the read function which by-default read till end. so, in while loop it didn't get any bytes. (read buffer reached end)

```
f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)  # reading 8 bytes
print(f'the total length of file is {len(f.read())}') # read rest of the file
```

**In third case**
Initially you read 8 bytes but while printing length you used readline which in turn reads a complete line and buffer reached on last line and in loop it prints 8 bytes per iteration as defined in loop.

```
f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)  # read 8 bytes
print(f'the total length of file is {len(f.readline())}')  # read 1 line
```

To have a better understanding use `f.tell()` to get the current position for the buffer.
see below example for case1:

```
size_to_read = 8

with open('sample.txt', "r") as f:
    f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)
    print(f'the total length of file is {len(f_contents)}')
    while len(f_contents) > 0:
        print(f_contents, end="**")
        print("\nbytes reached -- {}".format(f.tell())) #current state here
        f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first try this part of code `f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)` does read 8 bytes and then you just printed your variable here `print(f'the total length of file is {len(f_contents)}')`. In each iteration, your code is reading 8 bytes at a time.

In the second try you also read 8 bytes by this code `f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)`, but printing total amount of bytes in given file (reading file fully from start to end)  by this code `print(f'the total length of file is {len(f.read())}')` and then you are continue reading the file from the last read byte in `f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)` at the line 4.

In the third try you also read 8 bytes by this code `f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)`, but in this part of code `print(f'the total length of file is {len(f.readline())}')` you are reading next 8 bytes (starting from previously read 8 bytes). Therefore in this part of code `print(f_contents, end="**")` print statement is printing first 8 bytes that was read from file and saved in `f_contens` variable and then at the last line `f_contents = f.read(size_to_read)` you are reading 8 bytes starting not from first 8 bytes `f_content` variable, but from the second 8 bytes due to  `print(f'the total length of file is {len(f.readline())}')`.

Answer (score 1):

To not to be confused, just think about 2 things:

first, **where are you now** in the file ? (think of it as a mouse's cursor). second, **how much data** you are reading.

- with `read()` without an argument, you read data from where you are, until the end of the file. With argument, you read the data according to the specified argument in bytes.
- with `readline()` you read a single line "from where you are right now", until the end of the line.

After you read a piece of data no matter how much, your position is right there, so the next reading process begins from there.

Hope that solves your confusion.